# Import different components react from different files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How can I use component from another JS file in ReactJS.It says "Header is not defined".BTW I am using ReactJS without NodeJS.Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/babel" src="../Assets/js/react/Dashboard_components.js"></script>
//Here in Dashboard_components.js
var Dashboard_comp=React.createClass(
{
componentDidMount:function()
        {
            $('.ui.modal').modal();  
        },
        render:function()
        {
            return(
            <div>
                //Header exists in Base component js
                <Header/>
                <div className="ui two columns grid">
                    <div className="three column wide">
                        <SideNav/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="thirteen column wide">                        
                        <Stats/>
                        <Class_boxes/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            )          
        }
    })
```

Comment: where is Header component?

Comment: adding a <script> tag not work?

Comment: @ultro.It's a component in the Dashboard_components.js file.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your `Dashboard_components.js` file, and above the

`var Dashboard_comp=React.createClass(` line, add the line

`var Header = require('./yourpath/to/header.js')`

If you're using `ES6` you can simply 
`import Header from './path/header'`

Comment: A note here is that you need to transpile your code if you want to use require. You can use browserify, babel or something. Unless you are creating the templates server side in node.js. (But it seems like your are doing it client side)

Comment: I am doing it client side.NO NODEJS.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm..Seems like no-one got the answer so I am answering my own question.
Suppose there is a Header component in a Base_component.js file.So in order to use it in Other html's.Use this:

```
window.Header=Header
```

It would make component publicaly available for other files as well not the same js.